# Funnel options are not visible under Flurry Explorer tab

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

I have some logged events which I can view from Event Logs and Event Summary sections. However, when I want to create funnels using these events none of the options for creating funnels is visible.

This is what I see:

[image]

There should be some options in the right pane as it shown on the [documentation page](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/explorer/funnels/).

[image]

Why am I not seeing these options (Funnel Type, Funnel Steps, Dimensions, Filters)?